# Find the remainder in the following case where there's a infinite power tower of $7$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, tetration

> What is the remainder when
>   $$7^{7^{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}$$
>   is divided by 13?

I'm getting $6$. Is it correct?

Comment: And what does $7^{7^{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}$ mean?

Comment: How does your construction work? The sequence $7,7^7,7^{7^7},\dots$ is quite divergent.

Answer (score 6):

Note that 
$$7^{(7^k)}\equiv 6\bmod 13\iff 7^k\equiv 7\bmod 12\iff k\equiv 1\bmod 2$$
and that for any $n\geq 2$,
$$7\uparrow\uparrow n=\underbrace{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{7}}}}}}_{n\text{ 7's}}=7^{(7^{k})}$$
for some $k\equiv 1\bmod 2$ - specifically, $k=7\uparrow\uparrow (n-2)$. Here $\uparrow\uparrow$ is [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation). Thus, for any $n\geq 2$,
$$7\uparrow\uparrow n=\underbrace{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{7}}}}}}_{n\text{ 7's}}\equiv 6\bmod 13,$$
which is what I *assume* you meant by your question; the notation 
$$7^{7^{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}$$
does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$ (1+6r)^{1+2s}=1+(2s+1)(6r)+ \text{terms divisible by }6^2\equiv 7\pmod {12}$ for $odd\ r > 0$

So,  $$7^{7^{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}\equiv 7^{12s+7}$$  for some integer $s$.

Now,  $7^{12s}\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$,  as  $7^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$  as $\phi(13)=12$

$\implies 7^{12s+7}\equiv 7^7\pmod{13}$

$\implies 7^{7^{7^{7^{.^{.^{.^{\infty}}}}}}}\equiv 7^7\pmod{13}≡-7≡6$